# PHP save Class in other File and call it from another class

Tags: php

Im just tryed to work in PHP how in java, and I got a Problem with save Objects in other php File.
In java will looks like this:

```
package xxxx

public class Data {

public static Writer writer = null;

}
```

To save class there?

```
Data.writer = new Writer(file);
```

To get it from other Class or use it?

```
Data.writer.setLine("blablabla");
```

**But when I tryed do the same in PHP** there comes Problem then the objects will be not saved in the other file.
My Codes:

**ClassErrorLogWriter.php**

```
class ErrorLog {
    private $logfile = null;
    private $writer = null;

    public function __construct($file){
        if(file_exists($file)){
            $this->logfile = $file;
        }else{
            $this->logfile = $file;
            $this->writer = fopen($this->logfile, "a") or die("Unable to open file! ".$this->logfile);
            fwrite($this->writer, "New file was createt\n");
            fclose($this->writer);
        }
        $this->loadWriter();
    }

    private function loadWriter(){
        $this->writer = fopen($this->logfile, "a");
    }

    public function write($text){
        $date = $this->getDataFormat();
        fwrite($this->writer, $date.": ".$text."\n");
    }

    public function writeError($text){
        $date = $this->getDataFormat();
        fwrite($this->writer, $date.": ERROR: ".$text."\n");
    }

    private function getDataFormat(){
        $date = "".date("d-m-Y_H:i:s A")."";
        return $date;
    }

    public function close(){
        fclose($this->writer);
    }
}
```

**data.php**

```
$AuctualyPath = null;
$CurrentSqlConnection  = null;
$CurrentLogWriter = null;
$DefaultPageFile = "defaultPage/defaultPage.php";
```

**staticFunctions.php**

```
function createFile($file){
    $writer = fopen($file, "w");
    fclose($writer);
}

function checkFiles(){
  if(!file_exists("config.cfg")){
    createFile("config.cfg");
    $CurrentLogWriter->write("New File config.cfg was createt"); <- Error Here, $CurrentLogWriter is NULL
  }
}
```

**Application File (Start) must be called a specific function startSite()**

```
function startSite(){
    include "datas/php/ClassErrorLogWriter.php";
    include "datas/php/data.php";
    include "staticFunctions.php";

    echo $DefaultPageFile;

    $CurrentLogWriter = new ErrorLog(__DIR__."/logs/logFile.log");

    $CurrentLogWriter->writer("test");

    checkFiles();
}
```

After I Included Files I checked first if `Data.php` Variables are valid with printing `$DefaultPageFile`, then I defined new Logwriter in the Variable `$CurrentLogWriter` from Data File tryed to write it (it works). After I called Function from other php Class `checkFiles()` from `staticFunctions.php`. in the function `checkFiles()` by writing the Log It returns me Error then `$CurrentLogWriter` is NULL.
When I define Data.php as static Class so I must always define this Class and saving from date will not work. Can you help me by this Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The w3school documentation for [PHP Variables](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp) clearly states:

> A variable declared outside a function has a GLOBAL SCOPE and can only be accessed outside a function

When using the `include` statement, your included file is simply copied as-is into the current file. Therefore, your `startfile()` is the same as

```lang
function startSite(){
    include "datas/php/ClassErrorLogWriter.php";

    $AuctualyPath = null;
    $CurrentSqlConnection  = null;
    $CurrentLogWriter = null;
    $DefaultPageFile = "defaultPage/defaultPage.php";

    function createFile($file){
        $writer = fopen($file, "w");
        fclose($writer);
    }

    function checkFiles(){
        if(!file_exists("config.cfg")){
            createFile("config.cfg");
            $CurrentLogWriter->write("New File config.cfg was createt"); // <- Error 
            // Here, $CurrentLogWriter is NULL
        }
    }

    echo $DefaultPageFile;

    $CurrentLogWriter = new ErrorLog(__DIR__."/logs/logFile.log");

    $CurrentLogWriter->writer("test");

    checkFiles();
}
```

Notice that your `$CurrentLogWriter` was initialized **outside** `checkFiles()` and can only be used within `startSite()` which is *relatively* global to `checkFile()`.

A quick solution to this will be to pass `$CurrentLogWriter` as a parameter to `checkFile()` like this:

```
function checkFiles($CurrentLogWriter){
    if(!file_exists("config.cfg")){
        createFile("config.cfg");
        $CurrentLogWriter->write("New File config.cfg was createt"); <- Error 
        // Here, $CurrentLogWriter is NULL
    }
}
```

**OR**

You can optionally passed `$CurrentLogWriter` as a reference parameter, so that you can reuse it:

```
function checkFiles(&$CurrentLogWriter){
    if(!file_exists("config.cfg")){
        createFile("config.cfg");
        $CurrentLogWriter->write("New File config.cfg was createt"); <- Error 
        // Here, $CurrentLogWriter is NULL
    }
}
```

Then, call `checkFile()` as you did, but this time with the parameter

```
checkFiles($CurrentLogWriter);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple file_put_contents ?
[file_put_contents manual](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php)

it looks also you get messed up with fopen and fclose.
i would just collect all lines for such a class file and pump it out in a whole.
It is simple fast and error prune. If file_put_contens not work i would have a look also at the file write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

i think you were confused in File Management (fopen and fclose).

Comment: lets see if the logFile is abouth size of 1 mb and you write in more and more.
then watch from other side then abouth 50 to 100 Clients call this site? if I will use always file_putContents then it can come to problem then same informations can gona lost cause of different user with different internet speed. the user 1 call this site and user 2 too after, but user 2 has loaded faster. and the log from user 1 was ovverriten from user 2

Answer (score 0):

in the `checkFiles()` function the `$CurrentLogWriter` variable is a local variable that is not defined anywhere,

you either have to pass that variable as an argument like

```
function checkFiles($CurrentLogWriter){
  if(!file_exists("config.cfg")){
    createFile("config.cfg");
    $CurrentLogWriter->write("New File config.cfg was createt"); 
  }
}
```

or define it as a global like so

```
function checkFiles(){
  global $CurrentLogWriter;
  if(!file_exists("config.cfg")){
    createFile("config.cfg");
    $CurrentLogWriter->write("New File config.cfg was createt"); 
  }
}
```

and of course also define the global in the function where the vairable is created

```
function startSite(){
    global $CurrentLogWriter;
...
    $CurrentLogWriter = new ErrorLog(__DIR__."/logs/logFile.log");

...
}
```